# Flutter run don't finish

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart

In a new flutter project, I run flutter doctor command and it says everything is okay. When I try to run my app it doesn't finish or error out. It just says running. What should I do.

Comment: Are you sure that you call `runApp`?

Comment: Yes and I used vs code and android studio to run it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if everything is right with `flutter doctor` command, your app is probably initializing gradle which took some time before the app is properly running.

Run `flutter run -v` and you will see output telling you that the app is initializing gradle

This is how it looks in the Run window:

`Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...`

give it sometime to download gradle and it will run normally, of course this won't be an issue for future runs but always run flutter with the `-v` option

Comment: Initializing Gradle used to take up to 10 mins for me sometimes. My system was a dinosaur though so I expected it